# how to install the oauth in php

Tags: php, oauth

How to install the oauth in php. Can any one provide me the full description, links and all the libraries. I tried from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php) but I could not understand

I want to access the oauth token by the following code

```
$oauth = new OAuth(API_CONSUMER_KEY, API_CONSUMER_SECRET);
```

but this is not working because php extension for oauth is not installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, u need this file [php_oauth.dll](http://www.box.com/s/def614afe3acb2d6dd46) (windows)

Put into

```
/bin/php[version]/ext
```

And you need to change php.ini to load oauth (Dynamic Extensions)

```
extension=php_oauth.dll
```

Comment: Beware that the link points to php_oauth version 1-dev, which had lots of bugs.

Comment: Above URL is not working and even I've the .dll ( http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/1.2.3/ ) file I'm getting following error after updating the ini file.
**The program can't start because php5.dll is missing..**

Comment: Use dll from : http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/1.2.3/

Signature verified. But expired token error message. I believe its not having the right dll file issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of you have to download pear run it. than Install the Oauth extension. For windows you should have compiled file. of .dll file of extension. Best of luck

Comment: Hmm could be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can find the correct dll files [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth)

Make sure you select the correct file on the following factors:

1. PHP version
2. Architecture (x86 or x64)
3. Thread Safety (Yes/No)

You can find these info using php_info(); of your server.