# where can I get OAuth dll for php 5.4.4 for windows?

Tags: php, windows, oauth

Can anyone tell me where can I get the php_oauth.dll for php 5.4.4 for windows?

Comment: Do you know there is one, and whatever searches you've tried haven't proved fruitful?

Comment: I've looked on the web and there is no oauth dll for php 5.4.4, this is why I am asking if someone compiled/got it.

Comment: Asking for a specific file when you don't know if it really exists is probably the wrong way to approach it. First you need to find out if it even exists. Seeing your other (closed) question, Pierre (who apparently develops this extension) hasn't released one for 5.4.*. You might need to contact him or whoever runs that project to find out what options you have if you need that extension specifically.

Comment: Or just downgrade for the moment to 5.3 while waiting for a 5.4.4 release ...

Comment: Got an answer from Anatoliy. It can be found at: http://belsky.info/phpz/win/pecl/php_oauth-1.2.2-vc9-x86.zip

Answer (score 1):

Would you check this post, it discusses how to install it on Windows.

http://katieseaborn.com/masters/prototype/installing-oauth-on-windows/

As well as this old Stack Overflow post.
[how to install the oauth in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819107/how-to-install-the-oauth-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

I just had some issues getting this set up on WAMP.

1. Download the proper extension here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/
2. You will need to make sure you have a compatible version of php to work with it.  Since WAMP only supports up to a certain version of PHP you may need to install PHP manually.  Short article on that here: http://www.websanova.com/tutorials/php/manually-adding-php-versions-to-wamp

Answer (score 0):

You can download if from 'http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/1.2.3/'. Which is suitable for you