# Evernote oAuth error php (oauth )

Tags: php, oauth, sdk, evernote

while I am trying to run PHP SDK for evernote it gives following error

The PHP OAuth Extension is not installed !!

any help??

I am able to successfully create note using EDAMTest.php but it doesn't ask for credentials so if any one use that code every note comes in my account..

Comment: Can you do var_dump(); of your OAUTH class?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: oauth in D:\wamp\www\ever\sample\oauth\index.php on line 27

Comment: Can I see your code? I think you don't init oauth class..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh and (shameless auto-promo) you could also use a ready-to-use vagrant box : [laurent.sarrazin.io/2014/04/a-vagrant-box-for-the-evernote-php-sdk.html](http://laurent.sarrazin.io/2014/04/a-vagrant-box-for-the-evernote-php-sdk.html)

Comment: I use this method and now there is something wrong as I can not able to write '- client : run

vagrant ssh -c “cd /vagrant/evernote/evernote-sdk-php/sample/client/;php EDAMTest.php” 'in my cmd as per your given link.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install oauth?

I'm sorry, I don't use Evernote extension, so I don't know what is EDAMTest.php..

Try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819107/how-to-install-the-oauth-in-php) solution(if you use Windows) or find a way set up OAUTH for linux.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the oauth extension is not loaded.
I'd say that you did not configure the extension in the cli php.ini.

Find the location of the php.ini by doing this :

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

Add the oauth extension at the end of the file.

That should now work.